# Need an auto update programme that will install the software without any manual interference

Tags: installation

i want to create a programme  to auto update the software on client machine my question is how to run auto-installer to update the software.Actually we can download the current version of the software and we need to start installation without any manual interference.Once user click on the install update software need to be installed automatically without any wizard. any help will be appreciated.Thanks & Regards Harry.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the installation technology you use.

With MSI, you can pass `/passive` switch to msiexec command to prevent any interaction; add `/norestart` to prevent automatic system reboot. In case of MSI, you can also use Windows Installer API functions to fully programmatically install the package.

UI level can also be controlled from within the MSI package: from no UI at all to fully fledged wizard-like GUI. For example, you can display wizard interface when user installs your application for the first time; when you're preforming upgrade, you can show user only the progress or you can completely hide the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Like @AlexeyI says, it depends on the installer you're using.

For InstallShield-created 'setup.exe' installers, you pass the /s(ilent) switch.  If you need to provide answers to dialogs you also supply a response file containing the responses you want to give.